# Update to Windows 10 and now can't save files

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, windows-10-upgrade

When I try to save my files from applications in my Profile directories found under (C:\Users\Ben) I get an error that says "You don't have permission to save in this location. Contact the administrator to obtain permission"

The thing is though is that I AM the administrator.  I've tried to "Changing Ownership to my administrator login and my personal login, but the error never goes away.  Though I'm not 100% sure I've did the Change Ownership thing correctly.

I can save to the directory if I'm using Window File Explorer, but only after clicking the Admin only option of "Continue" when the warning dialog appears.

[image]

Any tips from anyone? Anyone else seeing this problem?

Comment: Can you save it to sub folders? You are not supposed to be saving stuff to that folder anyway, for organization's sake.

Comment: Saving to the sub folders of my user folder is what I mean (Documents, Pictures, Music, etc).  I can also save from the desktop using the file explorer if I give it the administrator "Continue" when the dialog is presented.  But in programs like a web browser or Word, it won't let me save.

Comment: @Havenard Added clarification to question

Comment: Changin ownership should solve this problem, so what You need to do step by step is: - Open `C:\Users` - Right click your user `Ben` - properties - security - advanced - owner - edit - make sure your user name is selected as owner - check the `replace owner on subcontainers and objects` - press ok. If this doesn't works we I will do some more research for additional solutions.

Comment: @divin3 I did all that previously thought I'm not sure I did chose the correct user. It was something like "administrator/ben". Now my computer went to sleep and when I try to wake it up it presented me with the login background, but would not show me any login fields. I restarted and now I get an eternal Windows Spinner. Restarted again. Spinner again. It seems Microsoft blew up my computer with their upgrade.

Comment: can You enter in safe mode?

Comment: There should be nothing about administrators when you change the owner. It should be your own account. If you change the owner incorrectly, your account will be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ben I right clicked my user folder - properties - security - advanced and then at the top clicked change next to owner and manually typed my name as shown in the list below the button (for me this was Benjamin-PC\Administrators).  That fixed the problem for me.  I had previously gone through trying to enable full control for my profile but changing the ownership this way is what finally did it for me.

Good luck.

Comment: This sounds like what I did, but I'm not 100% sure, and I may have messed it up before trying this.  It turned out that after my computer went to sleep I could not log in any longer.  It would never even present me with the fields to log in.  Even after several restarts Windows would load and just spin. If I clicked alt+ctrl+del I would get the login screen, but without the fields to log in.  So I just had to reinstall my Windows 7 copy and wipe my entire computer.   I'm now waiting my turn again to download Windows 10 and try again :(

Answer (score 0):

Try opening all the applications as an administrator. Right click and press open as administrator.

This seems to work with all applications under Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the solution. Go to Accounts and Sign on as a local account. This signs you out of the windows account and puts you back as a local administrator. You will have to create a password but who cares? No difference between using a pin and a password as far as I can see.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you explain what you mean what you state *This signs you out of the windows account*?